# Jquery Ajax call not successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I have the following code in Javascript and jquery

```
function abc() {

    alert("called 1");

    $.ajax({
        url: "abc.htm",
        context: document.body
    }).done(function () {
        alert("done");
    });
}
```

and my html button code is as follow

```
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="return abc();" />
```

for some reason the ajax call is not successful. I have added the required jquery files to the page.

Please help thanks.

Comment: Then add a fail handler and see what error you get, like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/4AVQ5/

Comment: And you're getting the first alert, right ?

Comment: I dont know what you doing but function header not correct. Should all ajax inside function abc

Comment: yes I am getting the first alert right

Comment: @adeneo I have added the fail handler but it not getting called

Comment: Did you open your console (F12) and check for errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify it like this...

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
alert("called 1");
$.ajax({url:"abc.htm",success:function(result){
$("#div1").html(result);
}}).done(function(){alert("d")});
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return anything to your html markup's onclick handler. Simply call abc() as in

```
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="abc();" />
```

Also, if you want more precise error handling then you can use the error and success ajax functions.

```
function abc() {alert("called 1");
        $.ajax({
            url: "abc.htm",
            context: document.body,
            success: function (data, status, xhr ) {
                console.log(data.SomeValue);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
            } 
        }).done(function () {
            alert("done");
        });
    }
```